# Single phase motor running of NO+NC switch?

Tags: motor

I have a single phase 220V 1600W electric motor that is a part circular saw with X2 capacitor in parallel. The original power switch was in strange configuration of NO+NC, although I was not able to find nowhere any replacement.

Powered from a terminal block for a short while and without a load (so technically NO+NO "switch"), motor was working fine.

The question is: Can I implement just a standard NO+NO switch instead?
Secondary question: Why does the manufacturer implemented it in a way that black wires are shorted only when saw is not operational, but disconnected when one push a trigger?

Picture shows the original connection.

[image: Original connection]

Comment: possibly a brake ... does the motor stop quickly when the trigger is released?

Comment: Honestly I do not know. I bought the saw brand new as "not working". Checking everything for shorts I have found out that something is not right with the switch. Broken plastic piece of safety lock was floating in the switch cover making it impossible to press. I had to dismount the switch and tried to put it back - this is impossible to be done.

Comment: use a DPDT switch

Comment: It's for dynamic braking. Shorting the motor will result in it stopping faster. (I've seen this done on a 50 kW/67 hp motor driving a mill with an impressively fast stopping time.)

Comment: Okay, I can live without braking. I will try to find a similar DPDT switch or will just leave those two wires disconnected. Thank you all for support! :)

Comment: "Okay, I can live without braking."  It's a circular saw so you might not. Rapidly stopping the blade is a safety measure.

Comment: @GrahamNye that was of course if I will not find DPDT switch. Spinning blade is no joke. One more thing - if there will only suitable DPDT switch with a speed control, can I use it? Amperage should not exceed the limit of the switch here.

Comment: As long as the speed controller is suitable for the motor that should be fine though suitable DPDT switches shouldn't be too hard to find. Any unused exposed terminals on the switch should be insulated.